# Oracle function for auto increment using in procedure

Tags: function, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I have table name render and i create a procedure for it.
My table is

```
 CREATE TABLE ROOM(
 ROOM_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
 ROOM_NO NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
 ROOM_DETAILS VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
 PRICE NUMBER(30) NOT NULL,
 ROOM_PACKAGE VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
);
```

And procedure is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_ROOM(
    p_room_id IN ROOM.ROOM_ID%TYPE,
    p_room_no IN ROOM.ROOM_NO%TYPE,
    p_room_details IN ROOM.ROOM_DETAILS%TYPE,
    p_price IN ROOM.PRICE%TYPE,
    p_room_package IN ROOM.ROOM_PACKAGE%TYPE)
 IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ROOM("ROOM_ID","ROOM_NO","ROOM_DETAILS","PRICE","ROOM_PACKAGE")
VALUES(p_room_id,p_room_no,p_room_details,p_price,p_room_package);
COMMIT;
END;    
/
```

But i want to make a function which will call in procedure and will use to increment ROOM_ID. How i create a function for doing this? 
I am trying to create a function but really i can`t

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AUTO_GEN
ID IN ROOM.ROOM_ID%TYPE
RETURN NUMBER
BEGIN
F_ID NUMBER(5);
F_ID=SELECT MAX(ROOM_ID) FROM ROOM;
 IF(ROOM_ID NULL) THEN
    ID=0;
  ELSE
    ID=ROOM_ID+1;
END IF;
RETURN ID;
END;
/
```

Comment: Sorry table name is ROOM

Comment: Must `ROOM_ID` be calculated? Why not use a sequence with a trigger?